# I am fetching some results from an api and setting it to state but when results arrive my component did not re-rendred

Tags: reactjs

I am using a weather api to fetch latest weather results and I have a component Main inside which i am rendering RealTimeWeather and DayDetails component.
I have set the results of the fetched data to state object so when it is recieved Main should re-render as you can see here,

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
// import { realtime_weather } from "../data";
import RealTimeWeather from "./RealTimeWeather";
import DayDetails from "./DayDetails";

const MainArea = styled.div`
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    max-width: 1235px;
    font-family: "Spline Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: auto;
`;

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (location) => {
                fetch(
                    `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=api_key&q=${location.coords.latitude},${location.coords.longitude}&aqi=yes`
                )
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.setState(data, function () {
                            this.forceUpdate();
                        });
                    });
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true }
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <MainArea>
                <RealTimeWeather realtime_weather={this.state} />
                <DayDetails realtime_weather={this.state} />
            </MainArea>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Here is RealTimeWeather,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const RealTimeWeatherContainer = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
`;

const Location = styled.div`
    font-size: 1.5625em;
`;

const Temperature = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
`;

const TemperatureIcon = styled.img`
    width: 70px;
`;

const TemperatureValue = styled.div`
    font-size: 4.6875em;
`;

const DegreeSymbol = styled.span``;

const TemperatureUnitSwitcher = styled.div`
    font-size: 1.5625em;
`;

const SelectedUnit = styled.div``;

const OtherUnit = styled.div`
    margin-top: 2px;
    color: #dbdde9;
    &:hover {
        border: 1px solid;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    }
`;

const TemperatureText = styled.div`
    font-size: 1.5625em;
    margin: 18px 0px;
`;

const LastUpdated = styled.div`
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9375em;
`;

const Extras = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0.9375em;
    gap: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
`;

const Extra = styled.div``;

function RealTimeWeather(props) {
    const [currentUnit, changeCurrentUnit] = useState("C");
    function toTime(unixTimeString) {
        let time = new Date(unixTimeString * 1000);
        let time_string = `${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes()}`;
        return time_string;
    }
    function changeUnit() {
        if (currentUnit === "C") {
            changeCurrentUnit("F");
            return;
        }
        changeCurrentUnit("C");
    }
    return (
        <RealTimeWeatherContainer>
            <Location>
                {props.location.name}, {props.location.country}
            </Location>
            <Temperature>
                <TemperatureIcon src={"https://ratentoi.sirv.com/sunny.svg"} />
                <TemperatureValue>
                    {currentUnit === "C"
                        ? Math.trunc(props.current.temp_c)
                        : Math.trunc(props.current.temp_f)}
                    <DegreeSymbol>°</DegreeSymbol>
                </TemperatureValue>
                <TemperatureUnitSwitcher>
                    <SelectedUnit>{currentUnit}</SelectedUnit>
                    <OtherUnit onClick={changeUnit}>
                        {currentUnit === "C" ? "F" : "C"}
                    </OtherUnit>
                </TemperatureUnitSwitcher>
            </Temperature>
            <TemperatureText>{props.current.condition.text}</TemperatureText>
            <LastUpdated>
                Updated as of {toTime(props.current.last_updated_epoch)}
            </LastUpdated>
            <Extras>
                <Extra>
                    Feels Like{" "}
                    {currentUnit === "C"
                        ? Math.trunc(props.current.feelslike_c)
                        : Math.trunc(props.current.feelslike_f)}
                    <DegreeSymbol>°</DegreeSymbol>
                </Extra>
                <Extra>Wind {props.current.wind_kph} km/h</Extra>
                <Extra>Visibility {props.current.vis_km} km</Extra>
            </Extras>
            <Extras>
                <Extra>Barometer {props.current.pressure_mb} mb</Extra>
                <Extra>Humidity {props.current.humidity}%</Extra>
                <Extra>Dew Point</Extra>
            </Extras>
        </RealTimeWeatherContainer>
    );
}

export default RealTimeWeather;
```

Here is DayDetail,

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
// import { realtime_weather } from "../data";

const DayDetailsContainer = styled.div``;

const DayDetailsHeading = styled.div`
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
`;

const DayDetailsContent = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 25px;
`;

const DayDetail = styled.div`
    width: 290px;
    border-top: 1px solid #8190b5;
    padding-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
`;

const DayDetailText = styled.div``;

const DayDetailTextHeading = styled.div`
    margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

const DayDetailTextContent = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
`;

const DayDetailTextContentLogo = styled.img`
    width: 50px;
`;

const DayDetailTextContentDesc = styled.div``;

function DayDetails(props) {
    return (
        <DayDetailsContainer>
            <DayDetailsHeading>Day Details</DayDetailsHeading>
            <DayDetailsContent>
                <DayDetail>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>Day</DayDetailTextHeading>
                        <DayDetailTextContent>Night Skies</DayDetailTextContent>
                    </DayDetailText>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>Night</DayDetailTextHeading>
                        <DayDetailTextContent>Night Skies</DayDetailTextContent>
                    </DayDetailText>
                </DayDetail>
                <DayDetail>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>Sunrise</DayDetailTextHeading>
                        <DayDetailTextContent>
                            <DayDetailTextContentLogo
                                src={
                                    "https://ik.imagekit.io/dchud9yflpr/sunrise_bhQw0Iuzr.svg?updatedAt=1641230704341"
                                }
                            />
                            <DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                                {
                                    props.realtime_weather.forecast
                                        .forecastday[0].astro.sunrise
                                }
                            </DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                        </DayDetailTextContent>
                    </DayDetailText>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>Sunset</DayDetailTextHeading>
                        <DayDetailTextContent>
                            <DayDetailTextContentLogo
                                src={
                                    "https://ik.imagekit.io/dchud9yflpr/sunset_xmlFFk7th.svg?updatedAt=1641230704467"
                                }
                            />
                            <DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                                {
                                    props.realtime_weather.forecast
                                        .forecastday[0].astro.sunset
                                }
                            </DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                        </DayDetailTextContent>
                    </DayDetailText>
                </DayDetail>
                <DayDetail>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>Moonrise</DayDetailTextHeading>
                        <DayDetailTextContent>
                            <DayDetailTextContentLogo
                                src={
                                    "https://ik.imagekit.io/dchud9yflpr/sunrise_bhQw0Iuzr.svg?updatedAt=1641230704341"
                                }
                            />
                            <DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                                {
                                    props.realtime_weather.forecast
                                        .forecastday[0].astro.moonrise
                                }
                            </DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                        </DayDetailTextContent>
                    </DayDetailText>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>Moonset</DayDetailTextHeading>
                        <DayDetailTextContent>
                            <DayDetailTextContentLogo
                                src={
                                    "https://ik.imagekit.io/dchud9yflpr/sunset_xmlFFk7th.svg?updatedAt=1641230704467"
                                }
                            />
                            <DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                                {
                                    props.realtime_weather.forecast
                                        .forecastday[0].astro.moonset
                                }
                            </DayDetailTextContentDesc>
                        </DayDetailTextContent>
                    </DayDetailText>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>Moon Phase</DayDetailTextHeading>
                        <DayDetailTextContent>
                            <DayDetailTextContentLogo
                                src={
                                    "https://ik.imagekit.io/dchud9yflpr/sunset_xmlFFk7th.svg?updatedAt=1641230704467"
                                }
                            />
                        </DayDetailTextContent>
                    </DayDetailText>
                    <DayDetailText>
                        <DayDetailTextHeading>
                            {
                                props.realtime_weather.forecast.forecastday[0]
                                    .astro.moon_phase
                            }
                        </DayDetailTextHeading>
                    </DayDetailText>
                </DayDetail>
                <DayDetail></DayDetail>
                <DayDetail></DayDetail>
                <DayDetail></DayDetail>
            </DayDetailsContent>
        </DayDetailsContainer>
    );
}

export default DayDetails;
```

Here is the error,

[image: Error Image 1]

[image: Error Image 2]

what is wrong in this code?

Comment: @adeys actually i get an object which has current and location object and yes it is giving the data in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add conditions, because your state empty by default and in child components you use properties of `undefined`. Also you can get `error` from api.

```
<MainArea>
        {Object.keys(this.state).length &&
        !this.state.error ? (
          <div>
            <RealTimeWeather realtime_weather={this.state} />
            <DayDetails realtime_weather={this.state} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
        )}
 </MainArea>
```